# to extract data from tif files using QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, qgis-python-console

I am brand new to GIS. I haven't been able to find the solution online, I think I don't know enough to be searching with the right terminology.

I have a number of tif files which I have successfully uploaded to QGIS as a raster layer. I also have a shapefile which I have uploaded as a vector layer. I am interested in getting the average pixel value for all those pixels of the tif file(s) which correspond to the area delimited by the shapefile.

I seek a solution I can perform in the Python console.

Comment: Have a read of https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_zonal_statistics.html that should expose you to some lingo. There are lots of plugins for QGIS, I haven't tried this one so can't attest to its suitability but if it works as described it should be exactly what you need.

Comment: You should have a look inside the [Zonal statistics plugin](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_zonal_statistics.html) . The code is probably there